# Fun Q2: Polygon inside a polygon. Find Test's area.

Tags: recreational-mathematics, area

A triangle is drawn of side length $a$. Then a square is drawn inside the triangle such that the area of the square is maximum and the bottom side is shared. Then a regular pentagon is drawn inside the square in a similar way... and it goes on till infinity. Refer diagram...
**Find Test's area.** $$$$
Test's area: Test shades the region with the maximum finite area and then continues the process such that no two shaded regions share the same boundary

[image]

The top point of the pentagon should be a bit lower in the diagram and isn't touching the square

Comment: In The figure provided, the pentagon touches The square on all its vertices. But then it is not regular anymore! A regular pentagon will not touch the square on all its vertices. Same goes for the higher polygons inside.

Comment: Yeah... didn't realize that. You are correct. The diagram is wrong. The pentagon is supposed to be regular. The top point should be a bit lower...